# Create a temp table that dynamically creates a list of dates with a defined daily target for each month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently have a list of monthly targets I want my output to return the list of dates followed by the monthly target split out equally amongst the dates:

```
Declare @CurrentMonthTarget int
set @CurrentMonthTarget = 1000

declare @endDateInteger date
set @endDateInteger = EOMONTH(GETDATE())

declare @StartOfCurrentMonth date 
set @StartOfCurrentMonth = DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)

declare @today date
set @today = convert(date, getdate())


select *
into #MonthlyTarget
from
(select  d.datekeyid,
         d.actualdate

from 
    datetabled d 
    where ActualDate between @StartOfCurrentMonth and @endDateInteger  
) DaysOfMonth;

SELECT
Datekeyid,
actualdate,
(SELECT @CurrentMonthTarget/COUNT(datekeyid) FROM #MonthlyTarget) As 'DailyTarget'

from #MonthlyTarget

Group by DateKeyID, ActualDate
```

This works well for the current month but I would like to be able to declare and set months until the end of the year ie July to December at the top of the query and have the output give the corresponding daily target for each date without having to repeat the function multiple times

Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below query

```
DECLARE @CurrentMonthTarget INT = 1000
DECLARE @monthStart DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)
DECLARE @yearEnd DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 12, 31)

;WITH NumberOfDaysInMonth
AS (
    SELECT MONTH(ActualDate) [month]
        ,COUNT(1) [numDays]
    FROM datetabled d
    WHERE ActualDate BETWEEN @monthStart
            AND @yearEnd
    GROUP BY MONTH(ActualDate)
    )
SELECT d.datekeyid
    ,d.actualdate
    ,@CurrentMonthTarget / n.[numDays] AS 'DailyTarget'
FROM datetabled d
JOIN NumberOfDaysInMonth n ON MONTH(d.ActualDate) = n.[month]
WHERE ActualDate BETWEEN @monthStart
        AND @yearEnd
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for! thank you for the help

Comment: If it helps, mark this as the answer so that it will be helpful to others too.